# Click add class doesnt seem to be working

Tags: jquery, class, addition

I am trying to add a class to a div that is clicked It doesn't seem to do anything?
Here is my jquery

```
 $("#dropdown-nav").click(function () {

this.addClass('open');
    console.log('test');

});
```

Comment: always use your console...

Comment: EITHER `this.className="open"` OR when you use jQuery `$(this).addClass("open")`

Comment: @mplungjan: The first will, of course, remove any other classes, if present... :-)

Comment: still not working nothing on console im using jquery-1.10.2.js would this be a problem?

Comment: @ConnorCushionMulhall Wait for document ready: `$(function(){$("#dropdown-nav").click(function () {   
    $(this).addClass('open');
    console.log('test');    
});});`  If still not working, then you are adding element dynamically (use delegation) or you have multiple elements with same ID

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I know, but that is rarely the case for beginners :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have one definite issue, flagged up by previous answers, and one potential issue (indicated by your comment to Abinash that doing what he suggests, which solves the first issue, doesn't make it work).

**Issue A**: `addClass` is a method of jQuery objects, not DOM elements, but within the `click` callback `this` refers to a DOM element. To wrap it in a jQuery object, use `$(this)` or `jQuery(this)` (in `noConflict` mode). See the previous answers.

**Issue B**: If that alone doesn't solve the problem, the most likely thing is that the `dropdown-nav` element doesn't exist yet when you're running your code hooking up your `click` handler. There are two ways to make sure it exists:

1. Put your `script` tag containing the hookup code *below* the element in the HTML file. It's best, generally, to put your scripts at the very end, just before the closing `</body>` tag. Or,
2. Use jQuery's `ready` callback.

If *those* don't solve it, other possible explanations are:

- The element doesn't have the `id` you think it has (`dropdown-nav`)
- Something else has hooked the `click` event and is stopping the event before your code sees it
- *(Reaching here)* You forgot to load jQuery

Here's an example solving both problems, using solution #1 for Issue B:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .open {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dropdown-nav">Drop-down nav</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Note that this is BELOW the element in the HTML, so the element exists
$("#dropdown-nav").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("open");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/aNizOVI/1)

Answer (score 2):

You syntax for `this` is wrong. Instead of

```
this.addClass('open');
```

write

```
$(this).addClass('open');
```

or

```
jQuery(this).addClass('open');
```

Use $ sign or prefix jquery when you are working with jquery

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with jquery ,`this`  should be `$(this)`

```
 $("#dropdown-nav").click(function () {   
    $(this).addClass('open');
    console.log('test');    
});
```

Seems,you just started with Jquery.

Learn : http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing $ try this

```
$(this).addClass('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

'#dropdown-nav`sounds like a large element to me. Are you sure it's not something like`#dropdown-nav .menu-item`? Anyway, all the suggestions above sound respectable and relevant. Here's one thing you may want to try:

```
$("#dropdown-nav").on('click',function (e) {
    alert('You actually clicked on ' + e.target);
    $(this).addClass('open');
    console.log('test');
});
```